# Scala code gen"<some code>" , what is its semantic?

Tags: scala

```
  override def emitNode(sym: Sym[Any], rhs: Def[Any]) = {
  rhs match {
    case im@ImplicitConvert(x) =>
     gen"${im.mY} $sym = (${im.mY})$x;"
    case _ => super.emitNode(sym, rhs)
  }
}
```

what does the code `gen"${im.mY} $sym = (${im.mY})$x;"` do?

Thanks

Comment: It seems `gen` is a custom [**String interpolator**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

Comment: Looks similar to `emitNode` at https://github.com/julienrf/lms-tutorial/wiki https://github.com/julienrf/lms-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/scala/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.scala#L54-L60 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252963/using-numeric-type-class-in-lms-lightweight-modular-staging

Comment: Looks like generating some code in Java, namely definition of a variable `Foo foo = (Foo) bar`.